# Is line number/sign click detectable in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there any way to detect clicks on line numbers or signs (just on line numbers or signs and nowhere else on the line) via a vim-plugin (i.e not extending vim code itself)?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you want this?

Comment: I'll write a plugin that lets clicking on line number or sign to fold/unfold.

Comment: Why would you need a plugin? You can already fold/unfold with the mouse, see `:help fold-foldcolumn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, offering a feature that is accessible only through the mouse won't get you many fans of your plugin, as many users avoid using the mouse.

Second, features such as the signs column are only marginally related to text editing, and as such aren't so fully featured as in IDEs.

Therefore, I don't think that's possible. Neither `v:mouse_col` (to be used with `getchar()`) can address the display cells outside the text buffer, nor does `v:beval_col` (for the balloon tooltips). You can only determine the width of the side columns by comparing `wincol()` with `virtcol()`.

Better provide a (configurable) mapping for your plugin's feature; this is more universal.

Comment: Well, vim has almost everything I used to get out of proper IDEs, except marginal features like this one. I think I'll fall back to using a thin vsplit for this. Thanks.

Comment: When did he say it would be accessible *only* through the mouse?